Best Way to Switch an Existing Partition with Data into an Empty Partition on the Same Table Without Requiring a Second Table
What would be the best way to create new partition and truncate the old one without requiring a secondary table.
Problem: All tables in a database are list partitioned on the same scheme and SourceId is the key used for every table.
I can update the partition function add a new partition called 'PEPSI_001' using the code below:
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME psSourceID NEXT USED [PRIMARY];
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfSourceID() SPLIT RANGE ('PEPSI_001');

My question is what the best way is to move data in an existing, non-empty partition named 'PEPSI' to a new empty partition named 'PEPSI_001'(in the same table) so I can then truncate the 'PEPSI' partition and new records can be inserted into it. More importantly can this be done without requiring a duplicate table to "switch" the partition into?


what the best way is to move data in an existing, non-empty partition named 'PEPSI' to a new empty partition named 'PEPSI_001'

You have to change the SourceId value on every row.  And when you do, the rows will move to the correct partition.  So just
UPDATE T set SourceId = 'PEPSI_001' where SourceId = 'PEPSI'

Thanks for the reply. If done this way, there will be no need to truncate PEPSI as all the records will have been moved? Updates against all tables could take some time but it seems more manageable than creating doubles of every table, or maybe not, hmmm.
